# Getting NaNs using Mann Whitney Wilcox Test in R

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I'm wondering if it is possible to compare two columns of data that I am comparing such as

```
457     X13   20.38263
458    X13   20.76624
459    X13   22.42405
```

vs

```
476      X13.1  102.61590
477      X13.1  118.82044
478      X13.1  135.40375
479      X13.1   83.35759
480      X13.1  142.96688
481      X13.1  102.10668
482      X13.1   94.59988
483      X13.1   93.98164
484      X13.1  114.86616
485      X13.1  115.51984
486      X13.1   99.43696
487      X13.1  132.94499
488      X13.1  136.99083
489      X13.1   98.14658
490      X13.1  114.45781
491      X13.1  141.01843
492      X13.1  136.31308
493      X13.1  202.44794
494      X13.1  147.23243
```

with

```
wtresult<-wilcox.test(dfcasted[,i],dfcasted[,(i+1)],paired=TRUE)
```

it gives me a warning  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes

and an NaN for the result. Is this because the two groups are of different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If `paired is TRUE`, a Wilcoxon signed rank test of paired data is performed.

If sample sizes are different - as in your case - you need a Wilcoxon rank-sum test and `paired is FALSE`.